# Use Docker-Secrets for Postgres-Credentials in Spring (bis)

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I have the same problem than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365203/use-docker-secrets-for-postgres-credentials-in-spring) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66073408/how-to-login-to-postgres-via-command-line-in-docker-using-secrets-outside-conta), but not the same cause, I have no extra character in my password file.

I am working with odoo, Postgres and docker-compose. I want to use secrets for the database user and password but it does not work:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: odoo_db
    image: postgres:14
    user: root
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_password
    volumes:
        - ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    secrets:
      - postgresql_password
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always             # run as a service

  odoo15:
    container_name: odoo_web
    image: odoo:15
    depends_on:
      - db
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - ./etc:/etc/odoo
    ports:
      - "10013:8069"
    tty: true
    command: --
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_password
    secrets:
      - postgresql_password
    restart: always             # run as a service

secrets:
  postgresql_password:
    file: odoo_pg_pass
```

My password file `odoo_pg_pass` contains only: 123 with no space and no CR or LF.

Here is the error message:

```
odoo_db   | 2022-09-13 06:43:00.880 UTC [1058] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "odoo"
odoo_db   | 2022-09-13 06:43:00.880 UTC [1058] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

EDIT: if I suppress the *secret* file and use environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` without `_FILE`, it works with a password like odoo, but not with 123. I need more testing.

EDIT: more testing results: with `odoo` as a pasword, the *secret* mechanism with use of the environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE` works, but not with another password. It is like if the password was hardcoded somewhere. But I have checked with a recursive grep and found nothing suspect in the whole tree.

EDIT: if I change the `POSTGRES_USER` in `db` and `USER` in `odoo15` to something different than `odoo`, I have the same problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. I'm running into the same issue.